# HttpClient.SendAsync() makes multiple calls

Tags: .net, dotnet-httpclient

I have an API client that was generated using the API's Swagger docs.  All of the calls work fine, except for one.

The one that doesn't work seems to be automatically retrying while none of the others do.  It sends a total of four requests.  The second immediately after the first, then the third and fourth at ten-second intervals.

Here is some of the generated code for the client:

```
    ...
    // Send Request
    if (_shouldTrace)
    {
        ServiceClientTracing.SendRequest(_invocationId, _httpRequest);
    }
    cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
*   _httpResponse = await this.Client.HttpClient.SendAsync(_httpRequest, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
*   if (_shouldTrace)
    {
        ServiceClientTracing.ReceiveResponse(_invocationId, _httpResponse);
    }
    HttpStatusCode _statusCode = _httpResponse.StatusCode;
    cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
    ...
```

I set breakpoints at the two lines with `*`.  With Fiddler, I can see that all four of the calls occur before the second breakpoint is hit.

I can't find any kind of retry policy in the request.  I've looked at the [`SendAsync()` source](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/tree/master/src/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http), but it contains no retry logic that I can see.

I am thoroughly baffled by this one.

### Edit 1:

Each time the request is sent, I get a 500 back.  That's expected for now, though, as the API is incomplete.

Comment: What are the status codes of the responses as seen in fiddler

Comment: @Nkosi I have edited...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer came via a colleague.  I need to manually define a retry policy.  He came up with this class (may be source from Google):

```
public class HttpTransientErrorDetectionStrategy
    : ITransientErrorDetectionStrategy
{
    private readonly List<HttpStatusCode> _statusCodes =
        new List<HttpStatusCode>
            {
                HttpStatusCode.GatewayTimeout,
                HttpStatusCode.RequestTimeout,
                HttpStatusCode.ServiceUnavailable,
            };

    public HttpTransientErrorDetectionStrategy(bool isNotFoundAsTransient = false)
    {
        if (isNotFoundAsTransient)
            _statusCodes.Add(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
    }

    public bool IsTransient(Exception ex)
    {
        var we = ex as WebException;
        if (we == null)
            return false;

        var response = we.Response as HttpWebResponse;

        var isTransient = response != null
                          && _statusCodes.Contains(response.StatusCode);
        return isTransient;
    }
```

and it's used in the client's `CustomInitialize()` method with this line:

```
SetRetryPolicy(new RetryPolicy(new HttpTransientErrorDetectionStrategy(), 0));
```